# Convergent integral implies convergent sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$f(x)$ is a continuous positive function s.t. the sequence $xf(x)$ is nonincreasing. Then show that $\int_1^\infty f(x) < \infty$ implies $\sum_1^\infty f(n)< \infty$?

I try to bound $f(x)-f(n)$ for $x\in [n,n+1]$ by something summable?

Comment: But the hypothesis is different? $xf(x)$ is nondecreasing here, right?

Comment: Oops, I had missed that :( – I have retracted my closing vote.

Comment: I made a small edit. $nf(n)$ nonincreasing to $xf(x)$ nonincreasing.

Comment: Doesn't $x \mapsto xf(x)$ being nonincreasing imply $f$ is nonincreasing? $(x+1)f(x+1) \leq xf(x)$ implies $f(x+1) \leq \frac{x}{x+1}f(x)$, and $\frac{x}{x+1} < 1$, so $f(x+1) \leq \frac{x}{x+1}f(x) < f(x)$. Now the Integral Test should apply.

Comment: @Hayden: You are right, that is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n \ge 2$ is
$$
 \int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) \, dx =  \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{ x f(x)}x \, dx
\ge  \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{ n f(n)}x \, dx
= n  \ln \left( \frac{n}{n-1}\right) f(n) \ge f(n) \, .
$$
The last inequality holds because, using $\ln (1+u) \le u$ for $u > -1$,
$$
\ln \left( \frac{n}{n-1}\right) = -\ln \left( 1 - \frac 1n\right) \ge - \left( -\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac 1n \, .
$$
It follows that
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \le f(1) + \int_1^n f(x) \, dx
$$
for all $n$, and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea. You can use that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx<\infty$ and therefore $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx = \int_n^{n+1}\frac{xf(x)}{x}dx \geq (n+1)f(n+1)\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}dx \geq (n+1)f(n+1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$ but $(n+1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\to 1$ when $n\to\infty$ so there exists $M>0$ such as $f(n+1)\leq M\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx, \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and you finish by comparison criterion.